# Cloning Application deployed in WebSphere to JBoss (WildFly)

Tags: jboss, wildfly, middleware, wildfly-8, undertow

I have a application which is running WebSphere Application Server & IBM HTTPS server.And below is the setup

1. Static Content is deployed in IBM HTTPS server under the DocRoot `/opt/www/static/xyzweb` and configuration is done to point to app jvm & contextRoot.
2. Application File (.EAR) is deployed in a jvm in WebSphere Application Server with contextRoot as `xyz`
3. This JVM is pointing to Oracle DB via JDBC - DataSource Connection. (uses ojdbc6.jar)

I want to setup the above architecture in my JBoss (WildFly) and run the application.Basically cloning it in Jboss AS

As of now, I just has launched JBoss (WildFly) in `Standalone Mode`, deployed a sample `.war` file with contextRoot as `abc` and able to launch the application.

`http://<<jboss-machine-name>>:8080/abc`

How can I achieve this.... For static content deployment, how can i use `undertow`....Please suggest

Getting below error while starting the EAR (running fine in WebSphere) in JBoss Wildfly

```
06:52:43,229 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."XYZ-Release01.ear"."XYZ.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."XYZ-Release01.ear"."XYZ.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "XYZ.war" of deployment "XYZ-Release01.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798) [vm.jar:1.7.0]

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017302: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/content/XYZ-Release01.ear/XYZ.war/WEB-INF/tld/JFPTags.tld" at [7,3]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.parseTLD(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:232)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
06:52:43,236 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (XNIO-1 task-2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "GMv3_PT")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"XYZ-Release01.ear\".\"XYZ.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"XYZ-Release01.ear\".\"XYZ.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment \"XYZ.war\" of deployment \"XYZ-Release01.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017302: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/content/XYZ-Release01.ear/XYZ.war/WEB-INF/tld/JFPTags.tld\" at [7,3]"}}
06:52:43,239 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "XYZ-Release01.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"XYZ-Release01.ear\".\"XYZ.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"XYZ-Release01.ear\".\"XYZ.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment \"XYZ.war\" of deployment \"XYZ-Release01.ear\"
```

Comment: You can use Undertow to serve your static content adding a file handler: `<handlers>
                <file name="static-content" path=/opt/www/static/xyzweb"/>
</handlers>` and referencing it with a location in your host: `<location name="/xyzweb" handler="static-content"/>` As for creating a datasource there is ample documentation on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Documentation

Comment: thanks for explaining the static part & regarding datasource connection , i was able to configure that..... But while EAR installation in JBoss (which is runing fine in WebSphere), I am getting error. Updated in the actual post

Comment: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/content/XYZ-Release01.ear/XYZ.war/WEB-INF/tld/JFPTags.tld\" at [7,3]"}} looks like your TLD is incorrect